# How to build APK file from Flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, android-build, android-buildconfig

Here I want `build` `apk` file for my flutter project. But a problem occurred when I `build` `APK` file with `flutter build apk` command. I already define `flutter SDK` path, `android SDK` path, `JDK` path in environment variable, but still this problem occurred. How to accomplish this?
Below I share the image of error which actually display in terminal.
[image: Click here to error Image]

> Another Error also I Put below side
>   [image: This Image display with above error.]

Comment: add any other error you are getting too. and it is always better to add errors and code as text, so community member can copy that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the sdk dir for your project

Go to your Flutter Project -> Android
if local.properties file was not there Create a file local.properties other wise open it
Open the file
paste your Android SDK path like below

- in Windows sdk.dir =
  C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
- in macOS sdk.dir =
  /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
- in linux sdk.dir =
  /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk

Replace USERNAME with your user name

I will suggest to run

> **flutter clean**.

before creating the app file

example of how a local.properties file data look like

**for Windows**

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\src\\flutter
```

**for Mac**

```
sdk.dir=/Users/UserName/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/UserName/Desktop/Workspace/Flutter/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

where **sdk.dir** is the sdk directory for android and **flutter.sdk** is sdk directory for flutter

Comment: I tried this but still same error occurred. Any other solution for this problem? @R7G

Comment: if you have windows machine put \\ instead of  \ in path , also please download Android SDK if not present in that path

Comment: I tried to change \\ instead of \, but this was change automatically when I hit `flutter build apk` command. Also I have already downloaded and set android SDK and NDK. Any other solution for it?